# Can't print a single row of an array I got an too many indices for array error?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, printing

I am trying to print out a single row of an array the code below just works fine

```
a = np.array([[1,2,6],[4,5,8],[8,3,5],[6,5,4]])
#Print second row
print(a[1,:])
```

My array is a bit more complicated(100 rows and 8 columns).

Here is my code when I want to print the second column I got an error saying too many indices.

```
import numpy as np
for i in np.arange(0, 106, 1.060606061):
   
                                        
    wl0 = 7.906e-07*i**4 - 0.0001709*i**3 + 0.009718*i**2 - 0.05276*i + 0.06008
    wl05 = 3.956e-07*i**4 - 8.837e-05*i**3 + 0.003919*i**2 + 0.1048*i - 0.1198
    wl1 = 1.122e-07*i**4 - 2.857e-05*i**3 - 0.0002459*i**2 + 0.2124*i - 0.271
    wl2 = -1.515e-07*i**4 + 2.998e-05*i**3 - 0.004428*i**2 + 0.3117*i - 0.3906
    wl3 = -3.898e-07*i**4 + 8.275e-05*i**3 - 0.008118*i**2 + 0.3918*i - 0.3196
    wl4 = -6.135e-07*i**4 + 0.0001285*i**3 - 0.01082*i**2 + 0.4195*i + 0.5945
    wl5 = -6.745e-07*i**4 + 0.0001367*i**3 - 0.01061*i**2 + 0.3661*i + 2.028
    wl6 = -7.106e-07*i**4 + 0.0001407*i**3 - 0.01027*i**2 + 0.3217*i + 3.049
     
    new = np.array([wl0, wl05, wl1, wl2, wl3, wl4, wl5, wl6])
    
    print(new[1,:])
```

Also tried with the following code

```
new = np.array([[wl0], [wl05], [wl1], [wl2], [wl3], [wl4], [wl5], [wl6] ])
```

but it still doesn't work. I just want to print a specific row (2nd row in this example. It doesn't really matter since I will be printing all rows one by one)

Comment: Looks like all the `w...` are scalars, so the `new` is a 1d array with shape (10,).  Check the `shape` and `dtype`.  You also create a new `new` with each `i`, and don't preserve the previous ones. Compare `a.shape` with `new.shape`!

Comment: Why the dotless `i`s? Aren't those used in the Ukraine?

Answer (score 0):

I think.. this should work..

```
import numpy as np
new=[]
for i in np.arange(0, 106, 1.060606061):
    wl0 = 7.906e-07*i**4 - 0.0001709*i**3 + 0.009718*i**2 - 0.05276*i + 0.06008
    wl05 = 3.956e-07*i**4 - 8.837e-05*i**3 + 0.003919*i**2 + 0.1048*i - 0.1198
    wl1 = 1.122e-07*i**4 - 2.857e-05*i**3 - 0.0002459*i**2 + 0.2124*i - 0.271
    wl2 = -1.515e-07*i**4 + 2.998e-05*i**3 - 0.004428*i**2 + 0.3117*i - 0.3906
    wl3 = -3.898e-07*i**4 + 8.275e-05*i**3 - 0.008118*i**2 + 0.3918*i - 0.3196
    wl4 = -6.135e-07*i**4 + 0.0001285*i**3 - 0.01082*i**2 + 0.4195*i + 0.5945
    wl5 = -6.745e-07*i**4 + 0.0001367*i**3 - 0.01061*i**2 + 0.3661*i + 2.028
    wl6 = -7.106e-07*i**4 + 0.0001407*i**3 - 0.01027*i**2 + 0.3217*i + 3.049
    new.append([wl0, wl05, wl1, wl2, wl3, wl4, wl5, wl6])
new=np.asarray(new)    
print(new[1,:])
```

output :

```
[ 0.01485117 -0.00434499 -0.04603783 -0.06495451  0.08691187  1.02740552  2.40451508  3.37881136]
```

Comment: it works just fine but I couldnt understand the idea behind it?

Comment: Your numpy array is just a 1d array and it doesn't have an index 1. Try taking the shape of your new array. you will understand. You are creating the array with only 1 set of w* values. You need to keep appending, if you want a multidimensional array.